# ply parse multi line block

Tags: python, parsing, multiline, ply

I would like to parse a file with the following content with ply:

```
option "option1 name"
option "option2 name"
variable1
{
    name: "var1"
    size: 5
}
```

where *option*, *name* and *size* are keywords, but variables are listed directly without any keyword, and they have properties inside {}.

The problem is with this multi-line variable declaration, that i cannot solve. When the parser gets the line "variable1", it throws an EOF error. If i give the variable declaration in one row, then it is ok, like this:

```
variable1 { name: "var1" }
```

How should I write a lexer-parser for this? Do I have to use states? Am I handling newlines incorrectly?

My goal is to get a python dictionary out of this, like:

```
{'variable1': {'name': 'var1', 'size': 5}}
```

Thanks you for any hints!

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote so far so we can help you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're reading from `input()` (or `raw_input()` for python 2).  Just was running into the same thing.  `input()` only reads one line.  So even though you pasted

```
variable1
{
    name: "var1"
    size: 5
}
```

The string that was read in was `"variable1"`.  You can do something like this as a workaround:

```
userinput = ''
line = input('> ')
while line != '':
    userinput += line
    line = input()

# pass `userinput` to your parser
```

After your block is complete, hit enter twice.  It should have the full string.